# Vaadin - How to open BrowserWindowOpener from a SINGLE BUTTON

Tags: java, pdf, vaadin, vaadin7

In the [Vaadin example of how to print a dynamically generated PDF](http://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book/#advanced.printing.pdfgeneration) they have a two step approach, first you click on the `OkButton` and then the `PrintButton`. The problem is that their code to open the PDF relies on creating a new `BrowserWindowOpener` which then extends the `Print` button in the `ClickListener` for the `OKButton`. In other words they have:

```
okButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) 
    {
        // Dynamically generate PDF - this is greatly simplified.
        StreamResource pdfResource = new PdfStreamResource();
        BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(pdfResource);
        opener.extend(printButton);
    }
}
```

This is great because the `Print` button is now linked to `BrowserWindowOpener` and will immediately open the window/tab when you click on the `PrintButton`.

The problem I have is that I don't want an `OkButton`, I just want to have a `PrintButton`. In this case I can't add

```
printButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) 
    {
        // Dynamically generate PDF - this is greatly simplified.
        StreamResource pdfResource = new PdfStreamResource();
        BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener(pdfResource);
        opener.extend(printButton);
    }
}
```

**In the `ClickListener` FOR THE `PrintButton`** because the first time you click it wont work. I then thought what if I had `BrowserWindowOpener` declared outside of the `ClickListener`, in the class that links the `PrintButton` and `ClickListener`, using something a dummy resource:

```
BrowserWindowOpener opener = new BrowserWindowOpener("");
opener.extend(printButton);
PrintClickListener printClickListener = new PrintClickListener(opener);
printButton.addClickListener(printClickListener);
```

And then pass the `opener` to the `ClickListener` so that I could do something like:

```
printButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) 
    {
        // Dynamically generate PDF - this is greatly simplified.
        StreamResource pdfResource = new PdfStreamResource();
        opener.setResource(pdfResource);
    }
}
```

However the issue here is that the first click generates a blank page.

**My question is how can I get the example working where the dynamically generated PDF is pushed to the browser window with just a SINGLE BUTTON**. All the examples for `BrowserWindowOpener` seem to always use two buttons. And the examples that declare it higher in the class hierarchy don't work for me, it's always an initial blank page.

Lastly, I would love to be able to do all this within the `ClickListener`, that is totally decoupled from everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of `BrowserWindowOpener` and use `UI.getPage().open()` to view your pdf file.

```
getUI().getPage().open(resource, "_blank", false);
```

Notice that this [method](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#open%28com.vaadin.server.Resource,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) is deprecated.

> As of Vaadin 7.0.0, the functionality for opening a Resource in a Page has been replaced with similar methods based on a String URL. This is because the usage of Resource is problematic with memory management and with security features in some browsers. Is is recommended to instead use Link for starting downloads.

Don't think it is possible to use `BrowserWindowOpener` in one button only without hacking in JavaScript.

**EDIT:**
I've achieved desired effect using BrowserWindowOpener. I've extended the class and added pdf generation every time when BrowserWindowOpenerState is requested. The thing is that I've searched for a method that is invoked after the click and before BrowserWindowOpener opens up new tab. The only method I could find is getState() - and only when the state of the component is dirty. I had to also add a flag in overriden getState method because:

1. setResource method invoke getState() method too, so I had infinite loop
2. to generate pdf only when its really needed

   ```
   public class BrowserWindowOpenerWithBeforeClick extends BrowserWindowOpener
   {

   private boolean pdfGenerated = false;

   public BrowserWindowOpenerWithBeforeClick(String url)
   {
       super(url);
   }

   @Override
   protected BrowserWindowOpenerState getState(boolean markAsDirty) {
       if(!pdfGenerated){
           StreamResource resource = ((RfgUI) UI.getCurrent()).getResource();
           pdfGenerated = true;
           this.setResource("url",resource);
       }
       return (BrowserWindowOpenerState) super.getState(markAsDirty);
   }

   public void setPdfGenerated(boolean generated){
       this.pdfGenerated = generated;
   }
   }
   ```

And pdf generation in your main UI class:

```
void pdfgeneration(final VerticalLayout layout)
{
    name.setValue("Slartibartfast");
    final Button ok = new Button("OK");
    ok.setId("ok-button");
    final BrowserWindowOpenerWithBeforeClick bwo = new BrowserWindowOpenerWithBeforeClick("");
    bwo.extend(ok);
    name.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)
        {
            bwo.setPdfGenerated(false);
            bwo.markAsDirty();
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(name);
    layout.addComponent(ok);
}
```

And getResource method:

```
public StreamResource getResource()
{
    StreamSource source = new MyPdfSource((String) name.getValue());
    String filename = new Random().nextInt() + "pdf_printing_example.pdf";
    StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(source, filename);
    resource.setMIMEType("application/pdf");
    resource.setCacheTime(0);
    resource.getStream().setParameter("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    return resource;
}
```

Notice that I had to change the **filename** everytime I generate new pdf file to avoid caching problems.

Comment: I don't have a file, it's all generated in memory on the fly, there is no file anywhere. Now I understand what you mean by write it to a temp file but doesn't that cause IO access whereas the other way it would all be in RAM and much faster. Is there any other way to open a dynamically generated PDF to print?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now everything happens in the memory.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I had seen that when I was coding. I can't remember where I read it but I remember somewhere in the API it suggested to use BrowserWindowOpener for this reason as well instead of open or Window. That's why I'm trying to so hard to use BrowserWindowOpener. This leads me to ask, do you know why there's no functionality to open a browser on a click? Why does it have to be linked by another button first? What's the reason why it's linked through the ClickListener of another button? That seems like a big oops to me so I have to assume there's some kind of technical reason?

Comment: From https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11110 "You can't rely on the click event reaching the server before the UI request for the popup as the two things happen simultaneously in the client." BrowserWindowOpener can extend every Vaadin Component - not only buttons - so I guess they didin't thought about method like 'beforeProcessClick'.

Comment: First thank you very much for all the effort, it's really appreciated. You found some amazing information!! Unfortunately though there's still some issues :( Do you realize that the PDF is being generated all the time. Not just on instantiation but also every time there's any updates. The performance is brutal Lastly, even if I changed the names of the pdf files randomly it still kept using the old pdf with the random number that was first created. I saw your trick but it didn't work for me. Either way the main issue for me is that you're generating new PDFs all the time vs once when clicking.

Comment: You did give me an interesting idea. I just created a fake button that was invisible  where I opener.extend(printButton) from the ClickListener on my fake button. I think did fakeButton.click() which hooked up the print button. The problem however is as you mentioned in your links, that the resource is set after the opener is opened, which results in a blank page on the first click. As well this causes a PDF report to be generated on each page load which is terrible.

Comment: I will look into it later on, it is an interesting challenge :)

Comment: Yes it is!! What surprises me is that considering how many people seem to be asking about this that it's not something Vaadin offers by default.

Comment: Btw, I did try to do something very weird, I tried to create a fake button in the listener and then call button.click() on it but that fails. I thought it might work since the initial button is still clicked by the user but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

- Vaadin 8
- Dynamic StreamSource

Double solution; at the occurence, generate a link and start to download client side. Also work only generated link to click for download, or start download client side after event server side, or click button.

Vaadin 8 generate for dynamic stream resource this url:

> `http://localhost:8080/{warPath}/APP/connector/{uiID}/{componentID}/url/{fileName}`

This snippet do: when click a button, a StreamSource was created, but the InputStream non generated at time. Then, a Link or Button component was created and attached to any component outside the click button listener. Also a BrowserWindowOpener was created and that extends Link or Button. A listener on the BrowserWindowOpener, when attached, generate the StreamSource dynamic link and open in new window (remember, in vaadin 8 the method Page.getCurrent().open(Resource, WindowName, openAsPopuo) is deprecated).
Finally, the strem (getStream()) was called only when the generated link is request.

```
    VerticalLayout vlay = new VerticalLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(vlay);
    
    Button butt = new Button("Click");
    vlay.addComponent(butt);
    butt.addClickListener(evt->{
        
        StreamSource ss = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
            
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {
                
                return new ByteArrayInputStream("Qualsiasi byte array".getBytes());
            }
        };
        
        StreamResource sr = new StreamResource(ss,"testo.txt");
        sr.setMIMEType("application/octet-stream");
        sr.setCacheTime(1l);
        //Button downlButt = new Button("Download");
        Link lnk = new Link("Download",null);
                    
        BrowserWindowOpener bwo = new BrowserWindowOpener(sr);
        //bwo.extend(downlButt);
        bwo.extend(lnk);
        
        bwo.addAttachListener(attevt->{
            String generatedURL = ApplicationConstants.APP_PATH+"/"+ConnectorResource.CONNECTOR_PATH+"/"+
                                  UI.getCurrent().getUIId()+"/"+attevt.getConnector().getConnectorId()+"/"+
                                  BrowserWindowOpenerState.locationResource+"/"+sr.getFilename();
            Page.getCurrent().open(generatedURL, "_blank");
        });
        
        vlay.addComponent(lnk);
        
    });
```